# Rails Remote Form does not post form parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, parameters, remote-forms

my question involves the following partial view with a remote form:

```
 <% remote_form_for :phone_number, :url => {:controller => "edit", :action => "add_phone_number" }, :update => "phone_number_div" do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :number%>
    <%= form.select :type, PhoneNumber::PHONE_TYPE%>
    <%= submit_tag "Add" %>     
 <% end %>
```

When the `Add` button is pressed, the `add_phone_number` action is posted to, but the form values are not in the params variable.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers won't pass the form values in the post if the form element is a child node in an illegal location in the DOM (like inside a TR, for example (and not in a TD).

I ran into this problem once.

Comment: Was this actually the problem in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have some sort of method for the form.

```
<% remote_form_for :phone_number, :method => :post, :url => { :controller => "edit", :action => "add_phone_number" }, :update => "phone_number_div" do |form| %>
```

Not to be picky but if you are using `remote_for_form` you want to have a resource to use it with. So you would want to replace `:phone_number` with `@phone_number` an instance variable that you instantiated in your controller. This keeps the code a little nicer and it is also in keeping with the conventions of Rails.

Also for problems like these [debugger](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/debug-rails-app-ruby-debug/) is your friend