# Rails 3 Remote Form Not Passing Parameters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form in Rails 3.0.3 that uses the new :remote=>true feature:

```
<%= form_for :photo, :remote=>true, :html=>{:id=>"photo_form", :multipart => true},     :url=>{:action=>"photo"} do |p| %>
<div id="photo_container">
    <div class="photo">
    <% if @card.photo.exists? %>
    <%= image_tag @card.photo.url(:full), :id=>"card_photo" %>  
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <label class="cabinet"> 
        <%= p.file_field :photo, :class=>"file" %>
    </label>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Upon submit, the photo field is not passed to the controller action. However, if I remove the :remote=>true bit, the param is passed just fine.

This question, [Rails Remote Form does not post form parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660258/rails-remote-form-does-not-post-form-parameters), seems to find the same problem, but the answer doesn't match here: my HTML is apparently valid and well-formed.

Anyone have advice here? I'm stumped.

Comment: Make sure you are including the javascript lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't send multi-part data remotely. This is because of the browser security model not permitting access to the `<file>` content, which would be required to stream it via an `XMLHttpRequest` as employed by the remote mechanism.

A remote form is generally equivalent to the same form without multi-part support.

If you need to do an async file upload, you will need to employ an `<iframe>` and submit the form to that target to prevent the main page from being refreshed. There are libraries to allow the framed page to update the master frame upon completion if required.

Comment: I'd also add that there is a limit to the size of an XMLHttpReq (AJAX). I don't think you can't POST a significantly large file via AJAX...

Comment: I should've added that I actually had this working in an earlier iteration of this site. I didn't touch this functionality since, but I know it worked at one point, so this must be possible?

Comment: *Facepalm* Turns out I was using the remoteipart plugin (https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart) and I've got it misconfigured. So tadman, you were absolutely right, but there's a better way than iframes to get around it! Thanks all.

Comment: It looks like that plugin does some kind of synchronous POST but at least lets you use the same jQuery hooks. Interesting.